# Trying to make a signal high for 5 clock cycles

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am debugging some uart code. I am trying to make the signal called `ld_tx_data_scope` a value of 1 after the first 5 positive edges and remain high for 5 positive edges and them have it go low and stay low. However, simulating the Verilog code provides this output for `ld_tx_data_scope`:

[image]

As you can see, it does not go high. The Verilog code is shown below:

```
module Uart_Proj(
clk_50,
tx_out,
tx_empty,
uld_rx_data,
rx_in,
rx_empty,
my_rx_data,
reset,
my_rx_clk,
my_tx_clk,
ld_tx_data_scope

);

input clk_50;
reg ld_tx_data; //
input uld_rx_data;
input rx_in;
input reset;

output tx_out;
output rx_empty;
output wire [7:0] my_rx_data; 
output tx_empty;
output reg ld_tx_data_scope; 

output wire my_rx_clk;
output wire my_tx_clk;


reg tx_enable; 
reg [7:0] my_tx_data;
reg rx_enable;
reg [16:0] ld_tx_counter_debug; //for debugging
reg ld_tx_toggle;
reg [16:0] ld_tx_data_scope_uptime;



always 
    begin
    tx_enable <= 1;
    rx_enable <= 0;
    my_tx_data <= 8'b01010101;
    ld_tx_data_scope <= ld_tx_data;
    end

always@(posedge clk_50)

 begin
 ld_tx_counter_debug <= ld_tx_counter_debug + 1;
 //rx_counter <= rx_counter + 1;

 if(ld_tx_counter_debug == 5 && ld_tx_toggle == 0) //5000
 begin
    ld_tx_counter_debug <= 0;
    ld_tx_data <= 1;
    ld_tx_toggle = 1;
 end
 
 if (ld_tx_toggle == 1)
 begin
 ld_tx_data_scope_uptime = ld_tx_data_scope_uptime + 1;
    
    if (ld_tx_data_scope_uptime == 5)//100
    begin
    ld_tx_data <= 0;
    ld_tx_data_scope_uptime = 0;
    end
 
 end
 
end
    
    
Baud_Generator inst_BG( 
.clk(clk_50), 
.txclk(my_tx_clk),
.rxclk(my_rx_clk)
);

uart inst_uart(
.reset(reset),
.txclk(my_tx_clk),
.ld_tx_data(ld_tx_data),
.tx_data(my_tx_data),
.tx_enable(tx_enable),
.tx_out(tx_out),
.tx_empty(tx_empty),
.rxclk(my_tx_clk),
.uld_rx_data(uld_rx_data),
.rx_data(my_rx_data),    
.rx_enable(rx_enable),
.rx_in(rx_in),
.rx_empty(rx_empty)

);
    
endmodule
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your 1st `always` block.  It simulates as an infinite zero-time loop because there is no timing control.  It keeps triggering itself in the same time step.

You could separate it into 2 procedural blocks:

```
initial begin
    tx_enable <= 1;
    rx_enable <= 0;
    my_tx_data <= 8'b01010101;
end

always @* begin
    ld_tx_data_scope = ld_tx_data;
end
```

The `initial` block just executes once at time 0.

The `always` block uses the implicit sensitivity list (`@*`) which only triggers the block when `ld_tx_data` changes.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2107 section 9.4.2.2 *Implicit event_expression list*.  It is better coding style to use a blocking assignment (`=`) in this block.

If you enable SystemVerilog features in your simulator, you should use:

```
always_comb ld_tx_data_scope = ld_tx_data;
```

Section 9.2.2.2 *Combinational logic always_comb procedure*